# Minimum Value of Triangle

Tags: triangles

The sides of a triangle are equal to integral numbers of units. Two of the sides are 4 and 6 units long respectively; what is the minimum value for the triangle's perimeter?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you, say, list all the cases where the third side is less than or equal to $4$?

Comment: If a,b,and c are the sides of a triangle, how does a+b compare to c?

Comment: Look up triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If one side is 4, and other side is 6. Let the third side be c.

Now we are looking for the minimum length, and we know that sum of sides is always larger than the third. (Here 6 is the largest.) So comparing,

$$4+c>6$$

$$c>2$$

Therefore, It's minimum value is 3.